# What is the meaning of == $0 that is shown in inspect element of google chrome for the selected element

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When I used inspect elements in Google Chrome there is always `== $0` at the end of the selected element. This is something new and I hadn't see it in the older versions of the Google Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Dev Tools remembers the last five DOM elements (or JavaScript heap
>   objects) that you've selected in the tab (or Profiles panel). It makes
>   those objects available as `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and `$4`. $0
>   returns the most recently selected element or JavaScript object, $1
>   returns the second most recently selected one, and so on.

See [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api) for more information.

Comment: So that I can access and use it in the console? what is it useful for?

Answer (score 3):

$0 is the current Element
You can do $0.addEventListener and other html stuff

```
$0 is just plain <div id="cBoxCurrent"/> dom node
```